# Canvas storing and rotating images

Tags: javascript, image, performance, canvas

I am currently building a HTML5 Tower Defense game in combination with HTML5 and a lot of Javascript. Currently I can draw +/- 2000 (and probably more) objects at 60FPS on my Nexus 6p. The trick to achieve this is draw images instead of using the pencil.

**Solution 1**

When I want to rotate an enemy, turret or bullet image I use the following code to generate the image:

```js
function calculateRotateImages(name, imagesrc, destination, drawheight = 50, drawwidth = 50)
{
 var images = [];

 var image = new Image();

 image.onload = function(){           
  
  rotate(0);
  function rotate(i)
  {
   imageCtx.clearRect(0, 0, 50, 50);
   imageCtx.save();
   imageCtx.translate(25, 25);
   imageCtx.rotate(i * TO_RADIANS);
   imageCtx.drawImage(image, -(drawheight / 2), -(drawwidth / 2), drawheight, drawheight);
   imageCtx.restore();

   var saveImage = new Image();         
   saveImage.onload = function(){
    images.push(saveImage);

    if(images.length != 360)
    { 
     i +=1
     rotate(i);
    }
   };
   saveImage.src = imageCanvas.toDataURL();
  }
 }

 image.src = imagesrc;

 var item = {
     name : name,
     images : images                     
      };
 destination.push(item);
}
```

This is the first thing I do when the page is being loaded, this will result in an array with a length of 360 (360 degrees). This leads me to my question; via this way I can achieve what I want but I don't know if this is the right way. For example, destionation[179] gives me a frame which is rotated at 180 degrees.

**Solution 2**

Another solution is a to draw all images at a hidden canvas (spritesheet) en cut a frame when I need one. I don't know what impact this will have on the performance (yet). What would be a better solution?

Comment: I understand the idea of "caching" your images, but doing that with every angle taken into account is over kill. Load your images and run your game. I really don't think it's worth creating a hundred billion of the same image before the game rather than rotating it when needed during the actual game.

Comment: If you're worried about performance, then I'd recommend resizing the images to the correct size depending on the screen size and then caching them. You could create another canvas, but again that's overkill. You only need one canvas.

Comment: @rugdealer I appreciate your feedback, but sometimes setting the source via image.src could sometimes take a lot of time and I have to wait until the onload event is launched before I can use it. This is required vor iOS & Safari. So generating and rotating them during the game is not an option at this moment.

Comment: that's why you load all your images before the game starts, but from your code it would appear you're loading an image and then recreating it at different angles. Just load your image once before the game starts and record it. You won't need to download the image during the game.

Comment: Another point of view, why don't you use a sprite sheet? Here is an example: http://www.williammalone.com/articles/create-html5-canvas-javascript-sprite-animation/

Comment: I have edited my question, but that's basically my second option/solution. What I want to know is which one is better from performance and maintainability aspect.

Comment: No, you should not be drawing your images to a hidden canvas. You should just cache the images in an object and then cut out the frame you want to draw it on your one and unique canvas. That would be the most efficient way of doing things. However, seeing that your image does not change at all, and you just want a basic rotation of the original image, simple load your image and cache it, then during the game before you draw on your canvas, rotate it and draw it on the canvas.